# Reactjs useSelector Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to use redux in my react typescript application

I have been able to create redux store and

also dispatch to redux

I want to get the value dispatched to the store

using useSelector but I am getting this error

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

My code

UserReducer

```
export const userReducer = (state=null, action) => {
   switch(action.type){
     case "LOGIN":
       return action.payload;
     case "LOGOUT":
       return action.payload;
    case default:
       return state;
    }
}
```

Login.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
const Login = () => {
  const reduxState= useSelector((state) => state);
  dispatch({
   type: "LOGIN",
   payload: "token"
 });
  return (
    <div className="__login">
       {JSON.stringify(reduxState)}
    </div>
  )
};

export default Login;
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <Routes>
         <Route  path="/login" element={ <Login />} />
      </Routes>
       
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.tsx

import React from "react";

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
// create store
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
reportWebVitals();
```

logout.tsx

Logout is where I click to change the state of the application by removing the token and change the state to null

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
const logout= () => {
  const reduxState= useSelector((state) => state);
 const logoutApp = () => {
      dispatch({
         type: "LOGOUT",
         payload: null
     });
 }
  return (
    <div className="__login">
        <span onClick={logoutApp}>logout</span>
    </div>
  )
};

export default logout;
```

Comment: Please, show the whole code. Especially the place where the component Login is used. Take into consideration that the state will be new on every dispatch. Actually, you should select a needed slice of the state with useSelector.

Comment: @AndrejKirejeŭ I have updated my code

Comment: Are there any places where the state is modified?

Comment: show your dispatches

Comment: @sojin it is dispatched on the login page

Comment: @AndrejKirejeŭ I have updated my question

Comment: Your dispatch method is called in a wrong way !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dispatch is just inside the login component. react functional component runs everything in the component on its every render.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
const Login = () => {
  const reduxState= useSelector((state) => state);
  
  dispatch({ //This dispatch will call on it's every render, so after success login it will call dispatch again, and then again ... it leads to an infinite loop 
   type: "LOGIN",
   payload: "token"
   });
  return (
    <div className="__login">
       {JSON.stringify(reduxState)}
    </div>
  )
};

export default Login;
```

The best method is to move it to a button click. or to a useEffect.

Method 1, login on button click

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
const Login = () => {
    const reduxState= useSelector((state) => state);

    const login = () => {
      dispatch({ 
       type: "LOGIN",
       payload: "token"
      });
    }
    return (
      <div className="__login">
         {JSON.stringify(reduxState)}
          <button onClick={login} >login</button>
      </div>
    )
  };

  export default Login;
```

Method 2. Call it in useEffect

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
const Login = () => {
    const reduxState= useSelector((state) => state);

    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch({ 
       type: "LOGIN",
       payload: "token"
      });
    },[]) //this useEffect will only call on its first render

    return (
      <div className="__login">
         {JSON.stringify(reduxState)}
      </div>
    )
  };

  export default Login;
```