# Rendering order for React apps - why does a "Too many re-renders" error occur?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and modifying an existing starter app.

I'm implementing a check to see if the user is logged in, based on the existence of a token in localStorage. I modified my App.js file from this:

```
function App() {
    let [ isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn ] = useState(false);

    return (
        <><Index isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} /></>
    );
```

to this:

```
function App() {
    let [ isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn ] = useState(false);

    const storageToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (storageToken) {
        setLoggedIn(true);
    } else {
        setLoggedIn(false);
    }

    return [same as above]
```

This change results in a `Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders.` error. Putting the check in Index.js works fine.

Looking into this some more (eg from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70757588/reactjs-useselector-too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-renders-to-p) or [this blog post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-solve-too-many-re-renders-error-in-reactjs/)), I understand that it's because you can't modify a state in the same function where you declare it with `useState` because that state change causes the overall function to run again. But my question is: why? I suspect this is background info about how React works / the order in which React calls components, so any background reading on that topic would be appreciated!

Comment: you set the state on every render. `setLoggedIn(false)` will cause a re-render even if `isLoggedIn` is false already and the function here is your render function

Comment: Thanks - yes, that's what I gathered from other posts. But I'd appreciate any background on why / when a render happens. In other words, for example here, I'm confused why App() gets re-rendered but not Index(), which it calls.

Comment: when you use Index() , it runs fine is because react store reference of index component, and until something change in state of index, it doesn't triggers  re-render. whereas when you write it the other way round, you are triggering set state from component outside render(), so  every time state update occurs, it executes the file as script line by line , and hence setState is executed and hence again react goes for re-render

Comment: To clarify, you mean if you copy the `if ... else` bit from `App` to `Index` and pass the state objects you don't get the same error anymore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/re-rendering-components-in-reactjs/#:%7E:text=A%20second%20or%20subsequent%20render,in%20their%20state%20or%20props.&text=A%20simple%20update%20of%20the,to%20be%20re%2Drendered%20automatically.) for understading how Reactjs actually works in these cases

Answer (score 1):

*App* is a functional component, which has its code run on every render. Changing state triggers a new render. By calling *setLoggedIn()* in the main body of the function, you’re creating an infinite loop.

The solution is to only read from localStorage when the component mounts/unmounts. This can be done with an effect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // code to run on component mount
    const storageToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (storageToken) {
        setLoggedIn(true);
    } else {
        setLoggedIn(false);
    }
  }, []);
```